# Conditional transition in MassTransit Automatonymous saga

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

I have some state in the saga and trying to implement status check retries until I get some satisfactory value in a message I receved.

Say, I have something like this:

```
.During(Pending,
    When(StatusChecked)
        .TransitionTo(somethingThatDependsOnStatusCheckedData)
```

I can only feed a specific state to `TransitionTo` but I want it to transition depending on the received message content, is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For received message content, you can use the conditional expression on the `When` clause.

```
During(Pending,
    When(StatusChecked, context => context.Data.IsMessageCondition)
        .Then(...));
```

Comment: Can I have multiple `When(StatusChecked, condition`) in one state, for the same message type?

Comment: Yes, but each .When() needs to have it's own execution branch. Your other question should give you a way to reuse the behavior.

Comment: With the comment _"Your other question"_ I assume you refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36192707/537842